# defining an inline default constructor C++

Tags: c++

```
public:
A();         
A(int B){*C = B - 1;};
private:
int *C;
```

I believe this is how to correctly call two default constructors but visual studio is giving me errors. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: What are the errors? You shouldn't have a `;` after the `}` of a function.

Comment: Whats your error? You gotta be more specific if you expect us to help you out.

Plus add {} beside the constructor that takes no arguments since it doesn't have a definition.

Comment: You are, at least, missing `class A {` and `};`. Please post a complete minimal program and the error messages it produces. http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 5):

This compiles. How does it differ from your program?

```
class A {
public:
  A() {} // Define (not merely declare) default constructor
  A(int B) { C = B - 1; } // Note: don't use uninitialized pointer
private:
  int C; // Note: not a pointer
};
```

Answer (score 2):

One constructor is indeed the default constructor. The other "constructor" is bound to operate more as destructor, however, as it will typically access unaccessible memory which in turn typically "crashes" the program. You should look up "member initializer list".